# How can I concatenate index to a function in Reactjs elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, ecmascript-5

I have many methods with numbering and i want to make a single render for input element using loop.

Here is my code:

```
{new Array(6).fill(0).map((inp, index) =>(
                        <input
                            key = {index}
                            className="input_otp"
                            theme={{ color }}
                            ref = {inputRefs[index]}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            onKeyDown={onKeyOTP2}
                            onFocus={onFocusOTP2}
                            type="tel"
                            maxlength="1"
                            value={state['otp'+ (index + 1)]}
                            name={'otp'+ (index + 1)}
                        />
                        ))
                    }
```

Now I want to add index to these event methods to make it dynamic `onKeyOTP+(index+1)` becomes

```
onKeyDown={onKeyOTP2}
```

Just like i did with other properties. Need help regarding this.

Comment: Why not have a common method which accepts index as a parameter?

Comment: Are you saying that component contains hard-coded methods like `onKeyOTP1`, `onKeyOTP2`, `onKeyOTP3`, etc.?

Comment: Can do that but that will require a lot of changes and i want to know if this way is doable.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, right

Comment: This looks like a really bad design. I don't know of any way to achieve such functionality - the only alternative would be to create a wrapping switch function, which would return appropriate function based on received index.

Comment: Are they all substantially different? I'm asking because this approach seems weird in general, and this might be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: yes they are different, i guess i will have to do it the other way around. Thanks guys

Comment: I still think there's a better approach, but you can do this: `const handlers = [onKeyOTP1, onKeyOTP2, onKeyOTP3, ...]` then use `onKeyDown={handlers[index]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function with this.

```
{new Array(6).fill(0).map((inp, index)=>(
                    <input
                        key = {index}
                        className="input_otp"
                        theme={{ color }}
                        ref = {inputRefs[index]}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onKeyDown={this[`onKeyOTP${index + 1}`]}
                        onFocus={onFocusOTP2}
                        type="tel"
                        maxlength="1"
                        value={state['otp'+ (index + 1)]}
                        name={'otp'+ (index + 1)}
                    />
                    ))
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 this.abc1 = () => {
  return '1';
}

this.abc2 = () => {
  return '2'
}

for(let i = 1; i< 3; i++){  
  let j = this[`abc${i}`];
  console.log("j is", j());
}
```

something like this